# Instagram iOS webview and position: fixed with 100% height

Tags: javascript, html, css, instagram

I'm trying to position a modal container with 100% height using `position: fixed` inside the Instagram WebView on iOS, and it looks like their webview is overlaying the navigation toolbars without resizing the actual document, so pieces of my content are hidden behind the toolbars, but I can't find a way to get the height programmatically in order to fix it. The screenshot below shows a striped column, starting at 0% and with each step as 10% of `window.innerHeight`, and you can see the overflow issue. Any ideas?

[image: screenshot]